# Can one use Combinatorial Game theory in PvP video games, specifically Fighting games?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I have always loved the idea of combinatorial games like Chess and Go, and in my head, I always believed that Fighting games can follow that same logic. So I decided to start writing a simple High School-level paper about the idea of using combinatorial game theory within the context of a fighting game. The only issue I now face is that, can a game such as a fighting game be used as a combinatorial game. My original thought was yes, as players only have a certain range of movement, all possible options are the same to both players and they know which ones the opponent and themself can use at any given point, and there is no chance involved. The only clause that hit me was "Players must play and cannot pass off a move" which in a fighting game, you can choose to do nothing about a heavy punch or light kick (as examples) , or you can block it, jump over it, ect. That makes me have to ask the question, Is it even possible (even if not practical) to use Combinatorial Game theory in the environment presented by a fighting game, or PvP video games as a whole.

Comment: Just because you're not allowed to do nothing in chess, if doing nothing is an option in your fighting game then "doing nothing" in your game is just as valid as doing something else. Also, your project sounds cool. If you could program some sort of automatic player that does well in your game (i.e. a "bot") then that would be cool. although you have to be a natural at programming to actually accomplish that...

Comment: It is theoretically possible to analyse a fighting game (e.g. frame by frame) but typically the status space will be very large. Your best bet would be to create your own simplified game, with just a few possible status. Even then, it is closer to game theory [in this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) rather than [in that sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory), because the players make moves simultaneously rather than in turn.